# Varying speed when reading sequentially from a HDD

Tags: hard-disk, performance, hardware

I have just got a new HDD and I wanted to test the sequential read speed (the whole disk). I used:

```
pv /dev/sda > /dev/null
```

The disk is 500GB WD VelociRaptor (WD5000HHTZ).

At the beginning the read spead is 194 MB/s but gradually it drops. At the end it was reading only about 118 MB/s. I am wondering if this is normal, and perhaps has something to do with the disk internal geometry. I did not expect such great variation. Besides, 118 MB/s is really slow, even for a normal HDD. The VelociRaptor is supposed to be a high end HDD for desktops.

Comment: It's normal, see this explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Data_transfer_rate Larger disks may be faster; e.g. a 500GB disk with 2x250GB platters will usually be slower than e.g. a 2TB disk with 2x1TB platters. 118MB/s doesn't sound bad to me for a 500GB disk.

Comment: FWIW, I just tested an external 1 TB USB 3.0 2.5" HDD (Seagate SRD0NF1) and it goes from ~ 130 MiB/s down to ~ 60 MiB/s while sequentially reading/writing the whole drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not unusual to have significant speed differences between the inner and outer tracks of an HDD.

See also [this](https://superuser.com/a/159934) answer.

Answer (score 1):

The number of sectors increases as you approach the outer edge.  If you think about the tracks as concentric circles, you can understand how they get bigger.

Originally, hard drives (and floppy) disks often used the same number of sectors on the whole surface of the disk.  It made it easier to control the disk for reading and writing, but it really wasted a bunch of the capacity of the media.

Then they moved onto differing zones, the smallest number of sectors on the inside, increasing for a middle zone, and the greatest number of sectors along the outside of the disk.

Most of this has been hidden from us for years, with hard drives pretending it is still a constant number of sectors per track.  This is actually an improvement, I remember coming across variants of UNIX that had databases of hard drives to know about the zones so they could optimize disk access.

118MB/s isn't too bad for a spinning disk.  Most of the time WD (and other vendors) report their speed as the maximum speed transferring from the *buffer* to the computer.  Your test is fairly kind to the disk though, since you are reading sequentially.  It allows the disks controller to read-ahead of you instead of reading just one sector at a time, so it can be moving the disk and starting to read while you are transferring data.